# How to remove lines from the files based on key values in a different file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file1:

```
1   a   aa
2   b   bb
3   a   aa
4   b   bb
5   a   aa
6   b   bb
7   a   aa
8   b   bb
```

and file2:

```
1
2
5
```

I need to delete all lines in from file1 where values in column1 are found in file2

Comment: That;s trivial with awk and there are hundreds of examples of doing it on this forum and across the internet. Please google it and try something **then** ask a question if you need help.

Comment: Could not find one based on column matching values

Comment: if you could find but that was not based on column, then only thing you wanted to know is that  how to apply it as column wise, can you show what did you find?

Comment: This (with column matching) is seriously the most frequently asked question on this forum and Stack Overflow. It's asked at least 1 or 2 times a week.

Comment: That's also `join -v1 file1 file2` if the files are sorted lexically on the join key. IIRC a similar question was asked here a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that both files are sorted lexicographically (with e.g. `sort -b`) on the first column:

```
$ join -v 1 file1 file2
3 a aa
4 b bb
6 b bb
7 a aa
8 b bb
```

This uses the `join` utility to extract all the lines from `file1` whose first column does not match any of the values in `file2`.

The default behavior of `join` is to produce the INNER JOIN based on the first column of both files, but with `-v 1` we instead get the unpairable lines from the first file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GNU `awk`:

**Solution 1**:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]} FNR!=NR {printf("%s",!($1 in a)? $0"\n": "")}' file2 file1
3 a aa
4 b bb
6 b bb
7 a aa
8 b bb
```

That 1st solution looks unnecessarily contrived, with a ternary operator `!($1 in a)? $0"\n": ""`inside the `printf` block.  I just propose it for generality's sake, meaning that if instead of merely deleting unwanted lines per your scheme, you ever wanted to replace them with `my_string`, you could just put `my_string\n` inside the empty string `""`.

**Solution 2**:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]} FNR!=NR && !($1 in a) {print $0}' file2 file1
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]} FNR!=NR && !($1 in a)' file2 file1
```

because `awk` prints the whole record (`$0`) by default.

`man awk` will give you a very good intro to `awk`, whatever your particular installed flavor.  If you still have questions after some surfing, just ask for specifics.

I bet someone will find a way to make this look even simpler. ;-)

Comment: there is no GNU awk specifc extension in your commands, it will work in all awks. also you can do `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1`

Comment: Never do `printf $0` as it'll fail cryptically when the input contains printf formatting chars. Always do `printf "%s", $0` instead. Ditto for printing any other input values.

Comment: @αғsнιη technically, the missing `;` or newline separator between the two condition-action pairs makes it non POSIX, but it's the maintainer of gawk that argued against it being allowed by the standard.

Comment: @αғsнιη: 2 things: re your first comment, I've always wondered whether skipping to the next record is somehow better than performing the complementary test (i.e. `FNR!=NR`) to the first block's test (i.e. `FNR==NR`). I used both interchangeably because I'm clueless on this. Re your second comment, thank you; fixed ;-)) .

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $0}' file2 file1
```

output

```
3   a   aa
4   b   bb
6   b   bb
7   a   aa
8   b   bb
```

Comment: Since this is more or less the same as in [another solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/666907/116858), you may want to add an explanation of why one should use this code over that.